# Change font size of only bullet points in beamer_presentation r-markdown

Tags: fonts, markdown, presentation

I am writing a presentation with markdown

```
---
title: "TITLE"
subtitle: "SUB"
author: |
date: "30/10/2019"
theme: "Frankfurt" 
latex_engine: xelatex
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes:
    - \author{NAME}
    - \institute[]{University}
---
```

I would like to create a slide where the font size is smaller than the rest

```
## First slide
* Normal text
* more normal text

## second slide
* small text
* small text
```

The second slide should have smaller text. Is this possible? I saw a lot of answers on the web, but one way or another mostly they referred to HTML or crashed on my computer when trying to run them

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use text size commands before the text you want smaller:

```
## First slide
* Normal text
* more normal text

## second slide
\tiny
* small text
* small text
```

More text size commands are listed [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles)